# Retrieve multiple images from MYSQL database using java

Tags: java, mysql, rest

I have uploaded some images in MYSQL database as a BLOB.Now I want to retrieve it through rest web services and java.I am able to retrieve one image.But how I can retrieve multiple images at a same time.What could be the best solution for this ?My Database it just like this

[image: Snapshot of Database]

Any Help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

My DAO class method is

```
public Response downloadById(int employeeId) {
    ResponseBuilder response=null;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    ArrayList<UserProfile> userProfile=(ArrayList<UserProfile>)getHibernateTemplate().find("from UserProfile where employeeId=?",employeeId);
    for(UserProfile user:userProfile){
        byte[] image = user.getProfilePic();
        try{
            //String tomcatDir = System.getProperty("catalina.home");   
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/img/"+employeeId+".png");
            File file=new File("D:/img/"+employeeId+".png");
            response = Response.ok((Object) file);
            response.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\"javatpoint_image.png\"");  
            fos.write(image);
            fos.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return response.build();
}
```

My Bean class is

```
public class UserProfile {

  private int employeeId;
  private String role;
  private byte[] profilePic;
public int getEmployeeId() {
    return employeeId;
}
public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
    this.employeeId = employeeId;
}
public String getRole() {
    return role;
}
public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}
public byte[] getProfilePic() {
    return profilePic;
}
public void setProfilePic(byte[] profilePic) {
    this.profilePic = profilePic;
}
```

}

I am putting the image in a folder and from there I am acessing it.

Comment: Please show your current code

Comment: `SELECT`. Loop. Read.

Comment: I am using hibernate and spring for this.As we are storing objects in ArrayList.What can be used for storing multiple images.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you make a first request to retrieve an HTML block listing all images `<img src=FURTHER-REQUEST?id=... ...>`. This then results in many follow-up requests, probably resulting in a bit of double work, a SELECT for a specific ID.

There are techniques for optimizing this, but they are not worth the effort normally. You could for instance return one large image combining all small images and via CSS display individual blocks for every user.

Comment: Thanks for you help sir.Can I do it from backend????? Means in my Code I am sending response for only one image.Can I send it for multiple images ????

Comment: You just send back a piece of HTML, say a `<table>` with `<img>`s, with an URL with individual id. Then the img request is handled separately with a SELECT with id, and returning a single image.